# What's the proper term for a function inverse to a constructor - to unwrap a value from a data type?

Tags: terminology, functional-programming, haskell, data

**Edit:** I'm rephrasing the question a bit. Apparently I caused some confusion because I didn't realize that the term [destructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_science%29) is used in OOP for something quite different - it's a function invoked when an object is being destroyed. In functional programming we (try to) avoid mutable state so there is no such equivalent to it. (I added the proper tag to the question.)

Instead, I've seen that the record field for unwrapping a value (especially for single-valued data types such as `newtype`s) is sometimes called *destructor* or perhaps *deconstructor*. For example, let's have (in Haskell):

```
newtype Wrap = Wrap { unwrap :: Int }
```

Here `Wrap` is the constructor and `unwrap` is what?

The questions are:

- **How do we call `unwrap` in functional programming?** Deconstructor? Destructor? Or by some other term?
- And to clarify, **is this/other terminology applicable to other functional languages**, or is it used just in the Haskell?
- Perhaps also, **is there any terminology for this in general, in non-functional languages**?

---

I've seen both terms, for example:

> ... Most often, one supplies smart constructors and **destructors** for these to ease working with them. ...

at [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#newtype), or

> ... The general theme here is to fuse constructor - **deconstructor** pairs like ...

at [Haskell wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Performance_Introduction#Algorithms) (here it's probably meant in a bit more general sense), or

> ```
> newtype DList a = DL { unDL :: [a] -> [a] }
> ```
>
> The unDL function is our **deconstructor**, which removes the DL constructor. ...

in [The Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/data-structures.html).

Comment: Destructor seems to be the most widely used term

Comment: This seems specialized to Haskell (a "destructor" in Haskell isn't the same concept as in C++. The name similarity is misleading). If you want the general concept of "unwrapping a value", you probably shouldn't use Haskell as an example. In C++-like languages, such an "unwrapper" may be simply a getter!

Comment: I suggest you remove the word "destructor" from the question, use "unwrapper" instead, and ask whether there is a general name for this pattern across languages :)

Comment: .unapply, or "extractor" is a rough analog in scala, but maybe there's no name because in most cases you simply pattern match

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several terms for the concept. Deconstructing is what I believe is common in Haskell circles, it is what Real World Haskell calls it.  I believe the term destructuring(or destructuring bind) is common in Lisp circles.

Comment: Interesting how the same thing gets a different term from one language to the next, like map turns into select in C#, haskell has fold lisp/java has reduce and ruby has inject, haskell has bind scala has flatmap C# has selectmany

Comment: It is indeed called deconstruction in the Haskell circles. If it sounds odd, keep in mind that Haskell has no objects - just values; So it goes without saying that the term has a different meaning. The great part is that 'deconstruction' is exactly what it does. On that note I personally think object deconstructors should be called something along the lines of object disposers. It is much, much more accurate.

Answer (score 7):

Destructor is the term used by C++ and maybe other languages that I don't know of. They are used to release ressources created by the constructor so they do the exact opposite of it. Maybe the concept does not translate literally to Haskell, but the term seems to be used at some places.

EDIT: Considering your edit to the question, I would call it an unwrapper then... I was able to answer the original question but now it has driven away from my knowledge so don't take this edit too seriously.

Comment: Note that C++/C#/Java's usage of the term "destructor" doesn't match Haskell's. Same word, different concepts.

Comment: @AndresF. Yes, that's why I added the sentence : `Maybe in Haskell this does not translate really well but I don't know the language.`

Comment: Fair enough, I removed my downvote. I think what's misguided is the actual question, which seems to be asking one thing, but is actually asking another! :)

Comment: @AndresF. Yes the question is misleading. The OP asks : `What's the proper term for a function inverse to a constructor?`. Unless the question is edited to be more specific to some Haskell concept, I will leave my answer as is.

Comment: Just a note, C# has finalizers but not destructors, which are different because finalizers have non-deterministic execution. So maybe edit your answer to not spread the misnomer of destructors in C#.

Answer (score 5):

In OOP, a constructor is a function or language construct that creates and initializes a new object ('constructs' the object), and a destructor is its dual, a function or language construct that cleans up after the object (by releasing any resources it holds) and deletes it.

However, since Haskell (unlike, say, C++) has garbage collection and doesn't support mutable state or other side effects (at least not directly), there is absolutely no reason for a destructor notion in the OOP sense. Also, Haskell constructors, unlike OOP constructors, have more applications than just object creation; they are also heavily used in pattern matching (see below for an example).

In your code example, 'unwrap' is a *record field*, and depending on how it is used, I might refer to it as an *accessor*, or maybe even a *getter* (although the latter is also used in a lens context, so it might actually be a bit confusing).

I have never heard the term 'destructor' (or 'deconstructor') used in a Haskell context myself; as Andres F. notes, however, it is sometimes used to refer to a function that undoes the wrapping introduced by a constructor. To my understanding, a record getter may serve as a destructor, but so could regular functions, provided that they get a value back out of a more complex data type. Examples include `maybe` and `either` from the Prelude.

Note that `unwrap`, in your example, can be several things:

- a function (just like any other): you can, for example, do `map unwrap [ Wrap 23, Wrap 42 ]`; this usage is roughly equivalent to a getter method in OOP.
- a record field specifier in a record construction: `let w = Wrap { unwrap = 23 }`
- a record field specifier in a record update: `let w' = w { unwrap = 23 }`; this is similar to setter methods in OOP (if you squeeze a lot).
- a record field specifier in pattern matching: `f Wrap { unwrap = a } = a`

It's probably best to think of Haskell constructors as something altogether different from OOP constructors. I suggest you (re-)read a good book on the Haskell programming language for a better understanding - ["Real World Haskell"](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) is really good, and I've heard good things about ["Learn You A Haskell"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). Both should have good explanations about constructors and record syntax in particular.

Comment: Evidence of usage of the term "destructor" in Haskell communities: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2010-April/003946.html and http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg26463.html . A "destructor" in Haskell lingo is an "unwrapper", a concept totally unrelated to memory management or object finalization.

Comment: My thesis director, who programs exclusively in Haskell, also uses the term "destructor" for an unwrapper.

Comment: Well, I had never come across the term. You are absolutely right that, when used, it has absolutely nothing to do with the destructor concept in OOP.

Comment: @AndresF.: Edited to honor your remarks.

Comment: @AndresF. This is interesting as I also never heard it referred to as a destructor, though that aside, would it not also be accurate to just refer to it as a record field, and the technique I see called "destructor" there as just a pattern match? I understand it's called "destructuring" when your match is pulling a list apart, is this perhaps a related term but in reference to an ADT? After all destructuring a list is just acting on an ADT as that's what a list is.. I got the term destructuring from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677806/f-version-of-haskells-list-destructuring

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I think so. Also see [stonemetal's answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/168677/16247)

Comment: @AndresF. Ah thanks for pointing this out! All makes sense then!

Answer (score 2):

Since there doesn't seem to be any cross-language convention, I usually call them *extractors*, because that's the term that Scala uses for that general notion, and because it's not likely to be confused with any existing usage.

Answer (score 1):

I think destructor is the broader term. Some languages like Java and VB.NET have a finalizer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171952/is-there-a-destructor-for-java

Comment: A destructor in C++-like languages performs cleanup actions before releasing allocated memory. A destructor in Haskell unwraps a value from its "outer layer" (you don't use it to cleanup anything). They aren't truly related concepts.

Comment: I guess I didn't realize this is a Haskel question.

Comment: It wasn't clear indeed. The question has now been retagged and reformulated :)